# ZGREP - Searching multiple, precise files

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search multiple zipped files from a single directory.  I'm using zgrep to currently search through either one individual file or all based on a wild card character.  Here's what I'm currently trying:

Files: 04112012.z, 04122012.z, 04132012.z, etc etc.

```
  zgrep <search criteria> 0412* | less
```

Is there any way that I can search say, only 04112012.z and 04122012.z specifically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the particular file names on the command-line, separated by a space, after all the required command switches have been given, but before you pipe the results to `less` in your case.

As an example, you could use the command below. The `-i` switch is used so that case is ignored (both upper and lower case results are returned) and `-E` is invoked so that extended regular expressions can be used:

```
zgrep -E -i 'gtk|layout' myfile1.gz myfile2.txt.gz myfile3.Z | less
```

As you know, you can use `*` instead of a filename to select all files in that folder so that `grep` searches through those. In addition, you could also use the `--include=regex` and `--exclude=regex` switches to target certain groups of file names, as is [explained in this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files).

If you have a look at `/bin/zgrep` (run `cat /bin/zgrep`), it is actually just a wrapper script, and all the normal `grep` command switches are valid when it is invoked. As is noted in the [zgrep manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/zgrep.1.html),

> Zgrep  invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files.  All options specified are passed directly to grep.  If no file is specified, then the standard input is decompressed if necessary and fed to grep.  Otherwise the given files  are uncompressed if necessary and fed to grep.

For more information, see `man zgrep`, `man grep` and the [respective](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/zgrep.1.html) [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/grep.1.html).